# Why doesn't my android tablet read my SD-Card, when it is readable by other devices?

Tags: android, sd-card, mobile-phone, memory-card

I have :

- A feature phone
- An Android Tablet - iBall Slide Brillante 8GB
- A 2 GB Sandisk SD-Card.
- A Windows-7 laptop computer.

My SD-Card was essentially for use in my feature phone. I have been using it for about 2-3 years in that phone.

Recently, I bought a tablet. When I put that card in the slot in the tablet, I get the notification saying :

> Preparing SD Card

After some time, the notification disappears. But when I open File Manager, it does not show the contents of the SD-Card.

- When I read the SD-card using a card reader on my Win7 computer, it works fine.
- When I connect the feature phone to my Win7 computer, it shows the contents of the SD-Card.
- When I connect any pen-drive to my tablet, using the OTG cable, it shows the contents of that pen drive in the File Manager.

Using that OTG cable, I connected my feature phone to my tablet (I didn't actually know what would happen, but I did it anyway.) So the connection was like :

> <kbd>Feature phone</kbd> --> <kbd>USB Cable</kbd> --> <kbd>OTG Cable</kbd> --> <kbd>Android Tablet</kbd>

It again showed me the notification

> Preparing SD Card

And then again, it showed my no files of the SD-Card.

But, after that, when I read the card on my computer, I found that some files were empty. I mostly have music files in the card, and only the music files were affected. The files exist, but they are of size 0 bytes. Barring the few files, all the others are safe, and run properly.

So, my questions are:

- How can I make my tablet read the SD-Card?
- What happened to those files, and can I recover them?
- Should I connect my feature phone to my tablet in the future?

Comment: One possiblity might be to format the SD card (Either from the tablet, or from windows), which should make it readable in the tablet (copy all important data to somewhere else, first) Connecting the feature phone to the tablet may _not_ be a good idea, since if it charges thought the USB cable, it may draw more power than the tablet can supply, which may result in damage to the tablet. Regarding recovering your files: there's file recovery software for windows, I'm not sure if it would work in this case though.

Comment: Not all "SD" cards are compatible. Also look at the specs, what the "max read" is on your Android. I remember when I got my first 10GB HDD about 20 years ago and my PC only read 2GB worth. A year ago I forgot about that and bought a 1TB HDD for my PC and it only recognized 200GB and didn't even let me partition the drive like the old days. The same thing happened when I bought an SD card that was too big (storage space) for my Android phone and didn't even recognized I had a card.

Comment: Android, phones, and Android tablets are off-topic here (hover on the tags), but there is a dedicated Android site (another you can add to your collection).  We should be able to migrate this for you so that you don't need to repost it.

Comment: @fixer1234 Please migrate it if you can!

Comment: @ejbytes My tablet has upto 32GB expandable memory.